Python Pandas monthly yoy% change when current month is partial
I want to calculate yoy% change for month level data, taking into account that the last (current) period is partial.
This has already been asked: Resampling and calculating year over year with partial data but I cannot understand the answer that was given.
My code is as follows:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(555)

# Create a sample dataframe
df_input = pd.DataFrame({
    'order_date': pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2024-07-10'),
    'customers': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(922, )),
    'orders': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(922, ))
})

df = df_input.copy() 
df.set_index('order_date',inplace=True)
df_monthly = df.resample('ME').sum()

print(df_monthly.tail())

            customers  orders
order_date                   
202403           1358    1513
202404           1581    1419
202405           1584    1565
202406           1456    1652
202407            389     378


Now I calculate yoy % change for every month and add it back to the original dataset:
yoy_change = df_monthly.pct_change(12).mul(100)

for column in df_monthly.columns:
    df_monthly[f'{column}_pct_change'] = yoy_change[column]


            customers  orders  customers_pct_change  orders_pct_change
order_date                                                            
202403           1358    1513             -6.215470         -13.095922
202404           1581    1419             -1.801242         -11.423221
202405           1584    1565             22.885958           3.232190
202406           1456    1652              7.772021          -6.508206
202407            389     378            -78.460687         -76.330620

However the pandas resample sums the partial month of July 2024 (through the 10th) and compares it with the full month of last year July 2023 when the percentage change is calculated. This leaves it at a very negative number when that isn't the reality (since we are comparing a full month to a partial one).
For example, the number of customers for July 2023 "up to the 10th" was 513, therefore the yoy % for the month of July 2024 should be -24 not -78.

Code
tmp = df.set_index('order_date')

tmp1 = pd.concat([
    tmp, 
    tmp.set_axis(tmp.index + pd.DateOffset(years=1))
        .resample('D').sum() # to avoid 02-28 & 02-29 duplicate
        .rename({'customers': 'prev'}, axis=1)
    ], axis=1, join='inner'
).resample('MS').sum()

out = tmp1.assign(
    pct_change=tmp1.pct_change(-1, axis=1)['customers'].mul(100)
)

out.tail():
            customers  prev  pct_change
order_date                             
2024-03-01       1358  1448   -6.215470
2024-04-01       1581  1610   -1.801242
2024-05-01       1584  1289   22.885958
2024-06-01       1456  1351    7.772021
2024-07-01        389   513  -24.171540

use DateOffset in a nice way.

Updated answer about additional question
tmp = df.set_index('order_date')

tmp1 = pd.concat([
    tmp, 
    tmp.set_axis(tmp.index + pd.DateOffset(years=1))
        .resample('D').sum()  # to avoid 02-28 & 02-29 duplicate
        .add_prefix('prev_')
    ], axis=1, join='inner'
).resample('MS').sum()

out = pd.concat([
    tmp1, 
    tmp1.pct_change(-tmp.shape[1], axis=1)
        .dropna(axis=1, how='all')
        .mul(100)
        .add_suffix('_pct_change')
    ], axis=1
).filter(regex='^(?!prev_)')

out.tail():
            customers  orders  customers_pct_change  orders_pct_change
order_date                                                            
2024-03-01       1358    1513             -6.215470         -13.095922
2024-04-01       1581    1419             -1.801242         -11.423221
2024-05-01       1584    1565             22.885958           3.232190
2024-06-01       1456    1652              7.772021          -6.508206
2024-07-01        389     378            -24.171540         -29.870130

If you don't use the filter function on the last line of out, you can also see the prev value.

Hi Panda Kim , thanks a lot for your answer, it works. However I am struggling to generalise your solution to a dataframe with multiple columns. I have update my question, thanks for your help.

@Giacomo i update my answer
